# Comparing two different rows according to one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Example dataset:

[image]

I have 3 different columns

1. FilmAdi(FilmName),
2. OyuncuAdi(ActorName)
3. OyuncuSoyadı(ActorSurname)

If user enter two different actor name e.g.

```
OyuncuAdi='Şener', OyuncuSoyadı='Şen' and OyuncuAdi='Kemal',OyuncuSurname='Sunal'
```

If is there any film which is played together, get the film name.
Sample output as below.

```
'Tosun Paşa'
```

Edit: I solved question after too many try, this query is solution which is my mind

```
select f.FilmAdi
from Oyuncular o 
join FilmOyuncular fo on fo.OyuncuId=o.OyuncuId
join Filmler f on f.FilmId=fo.FilmId
where o.OyuncuId in('4','5') --Oyuncu.OyuncuID 4 ve 5 olan oyuncuların oynadıkları filmler
group by f.FilmAdi
having COUNT(f.FilmId)>1
```

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: You type OyuncuAdi='Sunal' - Are you sure its not OyuncuSoyadı = 'Sunal' ? Can you please provide your code?

Comment: sorry, i edit it. I must be OyuncuSoyadi='Sunal'

Comment: Please provide t-sql code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare @filmactors table
(
film varchar(20),
firstname varchar(20),
surname varchar(20)
)

INSERT INTO @filmactors VALUES
('Tosun Pasa', 'Kemal', 'Sunal'),
('Tosun Pasa', 'Sener', 'Sen'),
('Av Mevsimi', 'Sener', 'Sen')

declare @firstActorName varchar(20) = 'Kemal'
declare @firstActorSurName varchar(20) = 'Sunal'
declare @secondActorName varchar(20) = 'Sener'
declare @secondActorSurName varchar(20) = 'Sen'


SELECT f1.film FROM @filmactors f1
INNER JOIN @filmactors f2 ON f1.film = f2.film
WHERE 
    f1.firstname = @firstActorName AND
    f1.surname = @firstActorSurName
AND f2.firstname = @secondActorName AND
    f2.surname = @secondActorSurName
```

Result:

```
Tosun Pasa
```

This uses a self-join.  Basically it selects all films with first actor and all films with second actor and joins them where the film is the same.

Comment: Code is running but not like my mind. I have actors table, film table and filmactor table which contain primary keys of actor and film tables. So, there are so many actors and films. I guess, your solution is only 2 actor

Comment: @furkanaltun But your question said "if user enter two different actor name", so I gave you a two actor solution.  What exactly do you want?

Comment: thanks a lot for help. I found my answer and i added to question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your table is called [FilmActor] you can do the following

```
SELECT FA1.[FilmAdi]
FROM [FilmActor] FA1
INNER JOIN [FilmActor] FA2
ON FA2.[FilmAdi] = FA1.[FilmAdi]
AND FA2.[OyuncuAdi] = 'Kemal'
AND FA2.[OyuncuSurname] = 'Sunal'
WHERE
FA1.[OyuncuAdi]='Şener'
AND FA1.[OyuncuSoyadı] = 'Şen'
;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you all movies which has more than one actor on it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT FilmName from (
SELECT [FilmName]
  ,[ActorName]
  ,[ActorSurname]
  ,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by filmname order by filmname) as rn
 FROM [LegOgSpass].[dbo].[actors]
 )X where X.rn > 1
```